# custom module view not loading

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating a simple custom module for my magento store, just a simple html/js form to select products and list them.
But I can't get the view working.

confix.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <mymodule>
                <version>1.0.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
            </mymodule>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <justlamps>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>mymodule</module>
                        <frontName>formtest</frontName>
                    </args>
                </justlamps>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <mymodule>
                        <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                    </mymodule>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

app/design/frontend/default/layout/mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/view.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
    </mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/default/template/mymodule/view.phtml

```
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: have you added an XML file (like: Mycompany_Mymodule.xml) to `app/etc/modules` ?

Comment: If you are new to magento do refer this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/view.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
    </mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <formtest_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/view.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
    </formtest_index_index>
</layout>
```

Make sure your layout file path should be:

**app/design/frontend/Your-Theme/Your-Package/layout/mymodule.xml**

Answer (score 0):

try to putting `mymodule.xml` and `template/mymodule/view.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/base/default/`

so final path should be `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

- First, file name should not be **`confix.xml`**, it should be **`config.xml`**
- In mymodule.xml, **`<mymodule_index>`** should be **`<justlamps_index_index>`**.

Please let me know if still you finds any problem.

Comment: It's not a justlamps_index_index should be `formtest_index_index` Frontname/controllername/actionname

Comment: frontname is displayed in browser address bar and the tag which is defined just within **<routers>** tag, is used to define layout handles.